# Flot - plotting chart with time not working

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

The following code doesn't plot a chart with Flot - it just becomes an empty chart with the x axis at 00:00 and the y axis from -1 to 1:

```
<div id='chart' style='height:200px; width: 300px'></div>
<script>
drawChart();
function drawChart() {
    var d1 = [[1360652400000, 22.5],[1360662400000, 24.4]];
    $.plot($('#chart'), d1, {xaxis: {mode: 'time'}});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the set of array brackets that represent the fact that it's the data series 1.

Use this instead:

```
function drawChart() {
  var d1 = [[1360652400000, 22.5],[1360662400000, 24.4]];
  $.plot($('#chart'), [d1], {xaxis: {mode: 'time'}});
}
```

And it should work fine.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmcdw/1/)

Ignore the code at the top of the JavaScript example, it's just the jquery.flot.time.js which I couldn't find a CDN for (but which is needed to use the mode: 'time')

Comment: You don't really need the `jquery.flot.time.js` code.  Works fine without it.

Comment: Good point. I swear I read that it was needed to use mode: 'time' but I can't find my source again.

Comment: `jquery.flot.time.js` appears to be necessary in the latest version of flot (0.8.2), but not in the version that fiddle uses (0.7).